# How can I add items to my actionbar?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, layout

I've tried searching around but I am only limited to a very minimal amount of internet usage till 16th so I was looking around on how I could implement buttons to my action bar.

Right so when you enter the playlist section on my app, there is an about button on the layout. But id like to move that button to my action bar, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Just see the [Google Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems).

Comment: My internet speed is super slow, and mosst google docs and or websites dont load. And I have stackoverflow cached so it loads fast.

Comment: voting to close the question as this lacks sufficient information to solve the problem and also mentions slow internet speed for not searching the docs

Comment: The poor guy is asking a question. Either answer it or don't. If documentation is given as a link with no explanation then there is no point of this forum. This forum is for people to help each others

Comment: @Snake read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226686/how-to-flag-questions-that-show-no-research-or-code. You will know why i voted to close

Comment: @Snake There is no point to replace documentation by SO. SO is for specific programming question, not tutorial or provide full code.

Comment: Fair enough... I just felt like helping him. I have been in a situations where I wanted hint to know where to start and generally i find google docs are sometimes too complicated for simple answers

Comment: @Snake Agree totally. A snippet can help instead of slapping whole document on him. Although OP must read it anyway, not whine about connection.

Comment: @Dhaval I know I am at fault for not reading these docs but the problem is, when opening these links they don't display. It loads and eventually says connection lost, so I don't see how I can view these properly.

Comment: Fair enough. But do keep in mind to ask questions only after scouring the google. Look for relevant questions as well, for this will save you from your Q's getting down-voted, which may even lead to block you from asking questions further. It isn't actually a fault. We are all like this at the beginner's level, in hurry for answers when errors are abound. Cheers bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example how you can add HELP icon to your action bar

Create a menu XML inside your menu folder like the following

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/help_menu_item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
    android:title="Help"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And in your activity do something like that

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.help_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.help_menu_item:
            //do your menu press here       
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.titlebar);

    homeButton = (ImageView) mActionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.titlebar_iv_home);
    menuButton = (ImageView) mActionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.titlebar_iv_menu);
    titlebar_title = (TitleTextView)mActionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.titlebar_title);
    titlebar_title.setText("TITLE");
```

you can give click events for the buttons also.Here i am taking one custom layout added to action bar. so create custom layout in your res/layout folder. and give appropriate id's to them.and give click events
hope this helps