# How can I launch a task/layout from my actionbar settings

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu, android-actionbar

So I have enabled the `ActionBar` settings panel. And I've edited my main.xml to look like this.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/about_one" 
        android:actionLayout="@layout/about"/>    
</menu>
```

My `MainActivity` implementation -

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.        
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

But when in app, I click the "about" button. It does nothing? So how can I get it to launch?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs before asking the question??. You are the same user who asked previous question and you mentioned slow internet speed for not searching the docs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026050/how-can-i-add-items-to-my-actionbar

Comment: Sorry I haven't, ill take a look at it next time!

Answer (score 1):

Override `onOptionsItemSelected`. Again look at the docs **Handling clicks on action items**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Quoting

> When the user presses an action, the system calls your activity's
>   onOptionsItemSelected() method. Using the MenuItem passed to this
>   method, you can identify the action by calling getItemId(). This
>   returns the unique ID provided by the  tag's id attribute so you
>   can perform the appropriate action

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle presses on the action bar items
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_about:
         // do something
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: upon opening the new layout, when you press back it exits the app, how can I make it go back to the main screen?

Comment: @SmallVille open new layout??. You don't open a layout. You navigate to a different Activity. Post the code for the same. By editing your question and posting a edit header keeping the old part.

Comment: nvm I ended up doing what you stated - Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 100);

Comment: Activities are added to back stack. Activity1 --> Activity2 click back button you navigate to Activity1. So it does not exit the app

Comment: @SmallVille further read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html